# Meaning and reference

Tags: meaning-in-context

What "others" and "do" and "they" refer to? I can't integrate my guess to the context.

> Daryl Bem (1967) posited that, from a conceptual perspective, people learn what they believe in the same way that **others do**, namely, by hearing what **they** say. If a noncoercive context (such as counterattitudinal role play) causes them to defend a particular position, they become more committed to that position. Bem’s self-perception theory offered an alternative explanation for the large literature of cognitive dissonance (Festinger, 1957). It is also clear that external pressure can undermine the desire to change. Brehm and Brehm (1981) adduced that an aversive state of reactance arises when people perceive a threat to their behavioral freedom. One motivational response is to intensify one’s attitudes and behaviors in opposition to the persuasion or coercion.

Comment: do replaces a repetition of the verb: learn; others=other people, they-other people

Comment: But you had no problems with *noncoercive*, *counterattitudinal*, *cognitive dissonance*, *aversive state of reactance*, or *motivational response*, all of which are pure jargon?  If you're comfortable reading this level of English, you should be able to tell us what you *think* these mean.

Comment: @Andrew I am studying psychology, So I have some information about psychological term, and its separated from my knowledge of English.

Comment: I think what I said was very obvious.

Comment: The first sentence is clumsy / semantically flawed. The writer doesn't mean *people learn what they believe in the same way that **other [people]** learn [what they believe]*, but that's the only syntactically valid way to interpret the words as written. What he actually means is *people learn what they believe **in the same way they learn other things***. Or perhaps *People learn [stuff] the same way everyone else learns [stuff],* but then one would have to ask *What does it mean to contrast [all] people with **other** people?* Who are those "people", if they're not *everybody?*

Comment: @Andrew: There really *is* a problem deciding what the referents of the queried words are, *because the text is badly written*. As a native speaker you might just ignore or not even notice the rough edges, but I can imagine it being a problem for any nns who assumes that "clever scientists" will always write perfect English.

Comment: people learn ||what they believe in|| the same way others learn. I agree it ain't elegant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers certainly, but OP says, "I can't integrate my guess to the context", and then neglects to tell us what that guess was.  I expect more detail than "what does this mean?"  in order to better answer the question.  We rarely let this slide with less advanced English speakers, why give it a pass here?

Comment: @Lambie: I never even noticed that additional "ambiguity". Are we talking about people learning *what they believe*, or *what they believe **in**?* If the word ***in*** is part of the phrasal verb *to believe in [something]*, that [something] is usually a deity or moral imperative. As opposed to simply believing something. So *I believe **in** God* = *I believe He exists*, but *I believe God* = *I believe what He says,* which is significantly different. In principle one could even write *They decide what they believe **in in** the same way that others do.*

Comment: @Andrew: I think you're being a bit harsh. I'm happy to accept that OP's problem isn't that he doesn't understand the likely *meaning*. What's confusing is *the way it's written* - unsurprisingly, because as I said, it's *badly* written.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no idea to tell you the truth. I agree it is badly expressed. So, my advice is email the author. :)

Comment: @Lambie: In context it seems pretty obvious to me that he means ***a person*** (any person, representative of all people in general) decides what he believes by listening to what ***he*** (that person] actually says. Hence the example of people ending up believing things just because they ***said*** them (perhaps in some "unreal" context where they're just acting out a role, rather that truly examining and articulating their personal beliefs).

Comment: Another source of confusion is: How many "parties" are involved? You learn to believe in something by doing what other people do who hear what "they" say. Indeed, who are "they"? Fumble Fingers, it is truly confusing. :) I simply cannot make head nor tail of it, really.

Comment: So, translating: I learn [I am a "people"] something like you [Fumble Fingers] learn something by hearing what [you Fumble Fingers] say? Is that it??

Comment: @Lambie: Indeed. But whereas that would be reason enough to VTC a similar question on ELU, we can't expect nns querents here on ELU to easily realise that their problems are caused *by the text itself*, not their lack of proficiency in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is so true, but personally, I think it is all the more reason to keep it open. :) Well, at least we now know what it means.

Comment: ...no. He means you (any representative person) don't really know *what* (if anything) you believe about lots of things. But if circumstances cause *you* to say something that embodies some particular belief (even if you were just reading out some lines from a play, to help your actor friend learn his part in it), you tend to (often, *uncritically, by reflex*) believe the words you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "others" refers to the people who are listening and "they" refers to the people who are talking and also learning what "they" believe.

To clarify, person A and B are talking.  We can rewrite the quote as clearly as possible

> Person A learns what Person A believes the same way Person B learns what Person A believes: by listening to what Person A says...

In other words, the researchers suggest that a person does not know their own belief until they hear themselves articulate it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really helpful. Do you agree that the original phrase (in my post) is misleading? Cause it apparently means Person A learns what Person A believes the same way Person B learns what Person B believes: by listening to what Person A (or B!) says... (Which is meaningless!)

Comment: This paragraph takes something that is hard to articulate clearly and does a poor/middling job at it.  Having said that, I don't think it's misleading; it's just hard to read.  For people in this area I'm sure the context makes it very clear what is intended.  I had to do a double take but it was plenty clear to me as well and this is decidedly not my area.

Comment: Ok thank. I meant the sentence itself.  the context (rest of the paragrap) also was not sufficient in my opinion, maybe cause  it is my area, and I didn't get it! :-) Thanks anyway